Заполнение блока combobox из .txt файла winforms c++
Требуется заполнить из текстового файла (заранее подготовленного) блок combobox, в последующем выбор переменной из этого блока должен влиять на действие кнопки. Абсолютно не могу понять/найти как это сделать.
Так же вопрос - есть файл заголовков .h и источника .cpp. Где должна быть логика программы? Во всех примерах весь код пишется в .h файле, должно ли так быть?
Перейти на c# не могу, поскольку планируется работа с библиотекой proj, оригинал которой на c++.

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Гуй делайте на C#. На C++/CLI - тонкую обёртку (wrapper) для библиотеки C++.

Так же вопрос - есть файл заголовков .h и источника .cpp. Где должна быть логика программы? Во всех примерах весь код пишется в .h файле, должно ли так быть? - Бегом учить основы C++! Забудьте на время про C++/CLI и WinForms. Учите основы!

Код загрузки из файла и привязки к комбобоксу можно написать в одну строку. Если не получается написать такой простой код, то... Учите основы!

@AlexanderPetrov Подскажите где собственно эти основы подучить, что почитать, прохождение курса с metanit не даёт мне достаточных знаний для winforms. Если говорить про гуи на С#, а обёртку на С++, где про это можно подробнее узнать?

@AlexanderPetrov допустим есть такой код
 StreamReader^ f = File::OpenText("C:/Users/itsme/Desktop/coordinate_systems.txt");  
 while (!f->EndOfStream) {  
  in_comboBox->Items->Add(Convert::ToString(9));  
 }  
 }```  

При попытке вызова функции - программа компилируется, ошибок не выдаёт, но не запускается.

Не пишите код в комментариях. Редактируйте вопрос.

На метаните курс по C++. Вы используете C++/CLI. Это два совершенно разных языка! / Если б вы только знали, как я задолбался повторять одно и то же на протяжении многих лет...

@AlexanderPetrov на то ведь новички и новички, чтобы задавать глупые вопросы. Зато как вы написали, я всё сразу понял. Но про метанит я написал, потому что Бегом учить основы C++! Забудьте на время про C++/CLI и WinForms. Учите основы!. За код в комментариях прошу прощения.
Чтобы не задалбываться повторять одно и то же на протяжени многих лет следует создать какой-нибудь раздел с вводной информацией, куда перекидывать всех "начинающих" дабы те, кто умеет читать, имели возможность ознакомиться с информацией без спама вопросами. На всех профильных форумах такие разделы есть...

@AlexanderPetrov и ещё раз прошу извинить, позволю себе немного своевольства. Моё ИМХО, если бы вы помогали с вопросами, а не корили за незнание, может быть у всех жизнь легче стала бы. Я понимаю, что я вам никто, вы мне ничем не обязаны. Но, вероятно, вести себя "как препод" в универе, который, если студент что-то не знает, если не объяснит из-за глупости вопроса, хотя бы   даст ему список литературы для ознакомления, намного лучше, чем казаться "злым матёрым дядькой" который только и умеет что ругаться на новичков.
